# ASP.Net MVC WebAPI - How to display json data in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I tried many things but I'm still unable to display data in View. I'm only getting a null result in View page.  When I debug using a break point, I can clearly see data in the variables but can't return it in View. Seems like I need a List...
**The aim is to return json data in a HTML View.**

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAPIStringAsync(Students model)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            string APIdatas = null;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                APIdatas = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }


            var stringJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Students>>(APIdatas);

            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return View();

        }


public class Students
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

and in my View, I have this :

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoMobile.Web.Models.Manage.Students>

@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
{

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
</td>


}
```

Comment: why are you returning json?

Comment: You need to `return View(model);`

Comment: I'm fetching json list thru webapi.

Comment: then you can use ajax call to bind data in view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First prepare the json data.
Then map this data to C# class

So first Create C# class which will hold the Json Data

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
}
```

Once C# class is created, you can fetch the json and deserialize it to C# class
Then You have to return this model to view.

```
public ActionResult GetJsonDataModel()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        Models.JsonModel.RootObject objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.JsonModel.RootObject>(json); //here we will map the Json to C# class
        //here we will return this model to view
        return View(objJson);  //you have to pass model to view
    }
```

Now in View you have to write below code:

```
@model ProjectDemoJsonURL.Models.JsonModel.RootObject
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetJsonDataModel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
<h2>GetJsonDataModel</h2>
@{ 
   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>userId</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>completed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Model.userId</th>
        <th>@Model.id</th>
        <th>@Model.title</th>
        <th>@Model.completed</th>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Please check below link:
in below blog, Json data is fetched from URL in controller method, then json is deserialized to a model class, then this model is returned to a view, and data is displayed in view

https://fullstackdotnetcoder.blogspot.com/p/how-to-read-parse-json-data-from-url-in.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm testing it and getting an error saying : **Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'JsonModel' does not exist in the namespace '....Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Comment: You have to create folder in Model-> JsonModel. Please refer blog in detail so that you can get an idea. Or open your C# class which you are using to map your json. Copy that class's namespace. In my case it was: ProjectDemoJsonURL.Models.JsonModel.RootObject   [ Here it is  SolutionName->ModelsFolder->JsonModelFolder-> RootObject Class. So this way you can find your namespace of your C# class ]

Comment: @ Amar Gadekar.  It's almost working but I need to retrieve a List of data, not only one. what if you want to return the whole List from; (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/) and display it in a View. How do I do it? I need the whole data in a List so that I handle handle it manually.

Comment: use foreach(var itm in Model) then iterate through model

Comment: when I try to run the project to fetch a list of data from **(jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos)**) I'm getting an error **({"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '.Models.Manage.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\n**
). it's only work when you fetch one data (jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1)

Comment: @ Amar Gadekar. Thank you so much. I'm now able to retrieve the whole list of 200 items thru **jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos** and display it in the View. Just need to add LIST when mapping json to C#. Here it is :  `var objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json); `    Also in the View page, need to add **IEnumerable**  like this : `@model IEnumerable<ProjectDemoJsonURL.Models.JsonModel.RootObject>`